# C#, charting, log scale how to set x-axis to bottom?

Tags: c#, charts

I have .NET CHART on VS2010 in C#

How to shift the x-axis to the bottom the Y-axis. See attached.

[image: Chart with x-axis that need to be ahifted to 0.0001]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this kind of thing:

```
_chart.ChartAreas["YourChartArea"].AxisY.Crossing = 0.0001;
```

(It might be `AxisX.Crossing` you need to set; I always get those mixed up!)

It works for non-logarithmic scales, but I'm not totally sure it works with logarithmic Y axes.